# duplicate foreign key column using sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a node project using sequelize, and have the following two tables

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var asset = sequelize.define("asset", {
    description   : DataTypes.STRING,
    maker         : DataTypes.STRING,
    model         : DataTypes.STRING,
    serialNumber  : DataTypes.STRING,
    barcode       : DataTypes.STRING,
    account       : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    usefulLife    : DataTypes.INTEGER,
    downtimeCosts : DataTypes.FLOAT,
    purchasePrice : DataTypes.FLOAT
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        /*Un estado es de muchas categorias, y no se puede borrar si tiene un activo asociado*/
        asset.belongsTo(models.assetState, {
          onDelete: "RESTRICT",
          foreignKey: {
            allowNull : false,
            name      : 'assetState_id'
          }
        });
      }

    }
  });

  return asset;
};


"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var assetState = sequelize.define("assetState", {
    state: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        assetState.hasMany(models.asset)
      }
    }
  });

  return assetState;
};
```

The problem is that when i check the asset tables in postgres I have two columns ("assetState_id", "assetState") I suppose that is because i give the name of the relation explicitly, as I can do to not generate the column "assetState"?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a primary key in the assetState table and then reference that in the association definition:

```
var assetState = sequelize.define("assetState", {
  assetState_id: { 
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
    primaryKey: true, 
    autoIncrement: true
  }, 
  state: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      assetState.hasMany(models.asset, { foreignKey: 'assetState_id' })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer, I declare the primary key in state table changing the a little the syntax, `assetState_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true // Automatically gets converted to SERIAL for postgres
    }`  because your syntax does not compile me, the second colum persiste the difference is only the name  assetStateAseetStateId

Comment: I fully see the problem now.  See my updated answer for how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you put the tableName in lowercase, the foreign keys will not being duplicated any more

dialect: 'mysql'